# While running oracle Goldengate for mysql version 19.1 getting warning--> !!! WARNING !!! --> libssl-2.17.0-stub.so

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I am using **oracle goldengate for mysql version 19.1.** While login to mysql DB from ggsci I am getting below warning. I have checked file libssl-2.17.0-stub.so, this file is not 
present in  LD_LIBRARY_PATH also not present in my linux machine. Due to this warning login not happening hence extract is not starting. Also did set up environment variables like-
MYSQL_UNIX_PORT
MYSQL_HOME
OGG_MYSQL_OPT_SSL_CA
OGG_MYSQL_OPT_SSL_CERT
OGG_MYSQL_OPT_SSL_KEY

`GGSCI > dblogin SOURCEDB DB@host:3306, USERID XXX PASSWORD XXXX`

Getting below error-
**!!! WARNING !!! --> libssl-2.17.0-stub.so
This is a stub library which can be used for linking only.  It must *not*
be used as a runtime library.  Please make sure this library is not found
in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.**

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow the steps from this doc link, and install OpenSSL and set the PATH as needed:

Check out this topic:
6.4 Other Programs and Settings for MySQL

Doc link:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/core/19.1/installing/installing-mysql1.html#GUID-14BA87AB-194B-483C-AECF-151A31F4AFC1

Let us know if that resolves it.